# porque este error: Creating bean whith name NombreRepository, No property parameters found for type?

Tags: java, sql, jpa

Tengo el siguiente servicio

```
public List<Factura> listFactura(String campo1, String campo2, String Campo3);
```

y su umplementacion

```html
@Autowired
private FacturaRepository repository;

public List<Factura> listFactura(String campo1, String campo2, String campo3){
       return repository.findByParameters(campo1, campo2, campo3);
}
```

y el Reporsitory

```html
public interface FacturaRepository extends JpaRepository<Factura, Integer>{
   @Query(name="detalleFactura", nativeQuery=true)
public List<Factura> findByParameters(String campo1, String campo2, String campo3);
}
```

Esta es mi entidad

```html
@Entity
@Table(name="FACTURA")
public class Factura implements Serializable{

@Id
@Column(name="ID_FACTURA")
private int idFactura;

@Column(name ="CAMPO1")
private String campo1;

@Column(name ="CAMPO2")
private String campo2;

@Column(name ="CAMPO3")
private String campo3;

//sus get y set

}
```

y tengo un archivo xml, donde va la consulta,

```html
<named-native-query name="detalleFactura"
      result-class="mx.com.proyect.entidades.Factura">

SELECT * FROM FACTURA F 
WHERE F.campo1=?1, F.campo2=?2 and F.campo3=?#

</named-native-query>
<sql-result-set-mapping name="mx.com.proyect.entidades.Factura">
<entity-result>
  <field-result name="idFactura" column="ID_FACTURA"/>
  <field-result name="campo1" column="CAMPO1"/>
</entity-result>
</sql-result-set-mapping
```

pero al levantar la aplicacion, me manda ese error
a que se debe?, me hace falta algo?

Error creating bean with name "FacturaRepository", No property parameters found for type Factura

Comment: Por favor, adjunta la clase Factura para ver cómo la has definido. Además, ¿qué intentas hacer en el respositorio? Lo pregunto porque  has anotado el método con "nativeQuery=true" pero no le has dado realmente una consulta SQL nativa

Comment: @IvanClavijos, Ya actualice mi pregunta, pero me sale el mismo error, que puede ser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es el nombre del método que has declarado en tu FacturaRepository.

Tal y como funciona Spring+JPA, cuando extiendes de JpaRepository, Spring aplica una convención basándose en el nombre de los métodos. Todos aquellos que sean "findByXXXX" son procesados por Spring y lo que encuentre, después del "By", asume que son los nombres de los atributos por los que tiene que filtrar. Por ejemplo, este método:

```
List<Driver> findByNameAndSurnameAndBirthDateAllIgnoreCase(String name, String surname, LocalDate date);
```

Le dice a Spring que ha de buscar, en la clase Driver, todos aquellos registros cuyo Name, Surname y BirthDate, ignorando las diferencias por mayúsculas o minúsculas, coincidan con los parámetros que estás pasando.

En tu caso concreto, la excepción dice:

No property **parameters** found for type

Es decir, Spring te avisa que en el tipo **Factura** (porque has declarado que el tipo genérico que se usa en tu interface es ese) no existe un atributo que se llame **parameters** ¿De dónde sale eso? Del nombre del método **findByParameters**.

¿Solución? Cambia tu repositorio y déjalo así, por ejemplo:

```
public interface FacturaRepository extends JpaRepository<Factura, Integer>{

    @Query(name="detalleFactura", nativeQuery=true)
    public List<Factura> buscaPorParametros(String campo1, String campo2, String campo3);
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, si me ayudo